# My session variables are lost when I redirect to main page with http

Tags: php, http, session

I am experiencing a very strange problem.
I have 3 pages :
home.php
forums.php
projects.php

Every page has a menu like this:

```
<ul>
 <li><a href='http://www.mysite.com'>Homepage</a></li>
 <li><a href='forums.php'></a>Forums</li>
 <li><a href='projects.php'></a>Projects</li>
</ul>
```

When the user is logged in  sessions are set up and in every page on top username is shown.
If I'm in Projects page and my username is on top as I am logged in and now I want to go to main page, when I cycle through projects and forums the username is on top and sessions are not lost.  When I click Homepage it goes to main page sessions are lost and the username is lost on the top.

I think the problem is with the first link **Homepage**.
When I do it **index.php** everything works fine but with this **http://** it is not working.  Actually sessions are still there but not showing up.

---

**UPDATE**
I think I found the problem
I converted all menu links to full links with http not only php files like this

```
<ul>
 <li><a href='http://www.mysite.com'>Homepage</a></li>
 <li><a href='http://www.mysite.com/forums.php'></a>Forums</li>
 <li><a href='http://www.mysite.com/projects.php'></a>Projects</li>
</ul>
```

And everything works fine.
I am curious and I want to expand my knowledge. If anyone knows why is this happening please let me know.

Comment: What code are you using to set the sessions?

Comment: Php sorry dont u see on the links i use php files
I use php functions to store sessions 
of course i use session_start();
then i retrieve sessions with $_SESSION['username'];

Comment: Does the domain name change when you go from a working to non-working page? i.e. Is the www always there?

Comment: No simply i use a href='projects.php' 
but the url bar it shows www.mypage.com/projects.php
also for forums in the code i put a href='forums.php'
and in the url bar it sits www.mypage.com/forums.php
Only for the main page i use http
Also if i click my logo i use http to go to main homepage
and sessions are not showing up

Comment: Is it possible your browser was displaying a cached version of the page from before the session username was implemented? Did you force a refresh on the "non-working" page?

Answer (score 0):

> converted all menu links to full links

No

`http://www.mysite.com` is not a valid URL, some webservers will assume that the path is '/', some browser will assume the path is '/' but most browsers will send the URL as is, and the webserver will usually send a redirect back to the browser.

As long as the host is the same in all cases or omitted, then the code will behave as you expect - but you really should use proper URLs to avoid subtle semantic issues i.e.

```
<ul>
 <li><a href='http://www.mysite.com/'>Homepage</a></li>
 <li><a href='http://www.mysite.com/forums.php'></a>Forums</li>
 <li><a href='http://www.mysite.com/projects.php'></a>Projects</li>
</ul>
```

or...

```
<ul>
 <li><a href='/'>Homepage</a></li>
 <li><a href='/forums.php'></a>Forums</li>
 <li><a href='/projects.php'></a>Projects</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Okay you say that i should use httpp://www.mysite.com/ iin all links right. Also i programmed a php file that cheks the url
and if the user typed only mysite.com on the url bar
this php file based on the page i go say forums.php
will take as a parameter the name of the page like this
checkUrl('forums.php') if url is mysite.com/forums.php the function will add
httpp://www.mysite.com/forums.php . this is working very fine.
is this solution ok ? note extra p on the links was added to prevent 
creatiion of link